# Simultaneous requests in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Assume I have two users in Thread Group and want them to fire two requests simultaneously. User 1 - HTTP Request A and User 2 - HTTP Request B.

Any ideas how to implement that ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 5):

To trigger the requests simultaneously, you need to place your each requests in different thread group as shown below.

[image]

Also, make sure that in the **Test Plan**, below option is unchecked.

[image]

Above settings will execute the request simultaneously. Below is the sample output.

[image]

Comment: To loop, please check the Forever option in each Thread Group. I checked it for my test plan. It is sending simultaneously for all the requests. Please accept my answer if works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add [Synchronizing Timer](http://Synchronizing%20Timer) to your Thread Group and set `Number of Simulated Users to Group by` to `2` like:

[image: JMeter Synchronizing Timer]

The Synchronizing Timer will pause the first thread until second one is ready to execute the HTTP Request sampler so both threads will be run simultaneously. See [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) article for more details.

Comment: And they will fire HTTP Request A simultaneously and then HTTP Request B simultaneously, but I'm looking for HTTP Request A + HTTP Request B at the same time